# Move files to subdirectories: /img/ab123.jpg --> /img/ab/ab123.jpg

Tags: linux, shell, regex, awk

I have a linux webserver with about 25.000 images in one directory. They are all lowercase and in the format two letters, three digits and jpg as the extension. Because that many files in one folder is getting difficult to manage I want to move them to subfolders based on the first two letters of the filename like this:

```
/images/ab123.jpg --> /images/ab/ab123.jpg
/images/ab383.jpg --> /images/ab/ab383.jpg
/images/sk234.jpg --> /images/sk/sk234.jpg
```

I already managed to list all about 250 different letter combinations and create subdirectories:

```
ls | awk '{print substr($0,0,2)}' | uniq | xargs mkdir
```

But I can't manage to move the files. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Bash can do the substring extraction for you.

Here's a one-liner that presumes that the destination directories already exist:

```
cd /images; for f in *.jpg; do mv "$f" "${f:0:2}"; done
```

This small script makes the directories for you and does the moves.

```
cd /images &&
for f in *.jpg
do
    pre=${f:0:2}
    if [[ ! -d $pre ]]
    then
        mkdir "$pre"
    fi
    mv "$f" "$pre"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it with

```
for i in $(find . -type f -maxdepth 1); do mv $i $(echo $i|awk '{print substr($0,0,2)}');done
```

Comment: Didn't work that way. But with a little modification it worked like this:

    for i in *.jpg; do mv $i $(echo $i|awk '{print substr($0,0,2)}'); done

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Many files, so let's avoid globbing, in favor of find(1):
And I use Zsh as shell:
A problem remains with filenames containing double quotes

```
find  -maxdepth 1  -type f -exec zsh -c 'a="{}";b=${a:0:4}; mkdir -p $b; mv -t $b $a'   \;
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe that simplest way is to use **`rename`** command with appropriate regex:

```
rename 's/^([a-zA-Z]{2})/$1\/$&/' *.jpg
```

Description:

```
$& - its original filename,

$1 - matched 2 first letters, used here as directory name
```

Comment: I tried this as I was curious to see if rename took sed-like syntax in expressions. This did not work.

Comment: @MIfe: There are two different versions of `rename`. One takes glob style arguments and the other takes regular expressions (`sed` like). Sometimes the latter is called `prename`. It's really just a simple Perl script. [One source](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/RMBARKER/File-Rename-0.06/rename.PL).